# Add rows and keys at run time to custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am working on an application in which i need to create rows and keys of custom keyboard pro-grammatically in java code , instead of using XML. 
Is this possible ? If yes, how we can do that.

Currently ,I am using XML and creating row in this way:-

```
<Keyboard android:keyWidth="10.0%p" 
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height" android:horizontalGap="0.0px"android:verticalGap="0.0px"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top" >
    <Key  android:codes="-21"   android:keyIcon="@drawable/arbiclinenew" />
    <Key  android:codes="-51"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/recentlinenew" />

</Row>
```

Basically , I need to show `"recent"` view in my keyboard which show all recently selected emoji by user same as in whatsapp. 
Please help..!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally ,I am able to create my own custom keyboard. We can create custom keyboard layout to show recent button. For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"></android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />


</FrameLayout>
```

Now, suppose on any key click, you need to show emoji or any other view, then we can set keyboard visibility  : invisible and can show your own layout.